# Inverse "In" filter - MS SQL reporting

Tags: reporting-services

Hopefully a quick one, but is there a way (short of using multiple "<>" filters) to perform the opposite of an "In" filter in SQL reports?

This thing:

[The In filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvTs2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have the expression return True or False and your filter becomes “Expression equals Value of True/False”.

Something like this for the expression perhaps?

```
=IIF(InStr("Blue,Green,Brown", Fields!EYE_COLOR.Value) > 0,True,False)
```

Then your Filter becomes an Equals filter where you filter on the value of True or False.

Comment: I don't think that works, because the "In" operator isn't available in expressions, but only in filters for tablixes and groups, or at least I think it is.

What I am trying to achieve is using a filter so that my group only contains rows which contain some particular values in some columns, and to do that I am using the In operator in the filter to define my list of string values ("My String 1", "My String 2", etc.).

Comment: Your expression doesn’t have to use IN. Provided an example in the answer.

Comment: Ah, perfect, thank you!

How odd that there's no native inverse of the In, though - it seems like there's no value to be offered by the In when you can use an InStr to do both things.

Oh well, that's me sorted, thanks so much for taking the time to provide an example.